# json_decode function php://input return Invalid JSON Format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

A new Datatype Introduced in mysql which is JSON.

[image: Text]

now when I get Raw data from header:

```
$_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
```

Result of `$data`

```
Array
(
[lines] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
                [name] => Panadol Extra
                [qty] => 1
                [price] => 11.00
                [total] => 11.00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [name] => Panadol Simple
                [qty] => 1
                [price] => 5.00
                [total] => 5.00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Panadol
                [qty] => 1
                [price] => 1.00
                [total] => 1.00
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Panadol Extra
                [qty] => 1
                [price] => 1.00
                [total] => 1.00
            )

    )

[discount] => 0
[date] => 2019-11-22T16:31:21+05:00
[paid] => 18
[user_id] => 1
[serial] => 35

)
```

am getting this error when i store data in mysql

> Invalid Query!Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in
>   value for column 'sales.Invoice'.

here is my query:

```
require_once 'config/config.php';
$_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_json);
exit();

$query = "INSERT INTO `sales` 
(`UserId`,`invoice`,`Discount`,`Paid`,`Serial`) 
Values('','','','','');";

$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result)
echo "Data Inserted Successfully!";
else
echo "Invalid Query!".$db->error;
```

i need to store discount,paid,user_id,serial and lines(json format) into table.help me to store that data into sales. how do i convert `lines` into json format. i can store other object discount paid serial using extract function but unbale to convert `lines` data into json format

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking.  the screenshot is not useful other than to orient us that _you are using phpmyadmin and looking at a fieldtype of json_.  The $_data array is useful; however, what happens between `php://input`) and the error is required to understand what is going awry.  Please at least edit the question and show the code that is trying to submit to the `Invoice` table.

Comment: can you help me remotely

Comment: edit your post.  take down the image, replace it with one that shows your column names.  post the section of the code that takes `$_data` and creates an _insert query_.

Comment: I have updated question more specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution i found.

```
$_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
extract($_json);

$invoice = json_encode($lines);

$query = "INSERT INTO `sales` (`UserId`,`invoice`,`Discount`,`Paid`,`Serial`) 
Values('$user_id','$invoice','$discount','$paid','$serial');";

$result = $db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are decoding the JSON so it's creating a problem. Don't decode it directly store the JSON variable